# How to make an external PCI adapter that runs on USB3.0?

Tags: design, usb-device, adapter, pcie

Motivated by old PCI (NOT PCIe) cards, and laptops without expansion slots, I want to try making a PCI-over-USB 3.0 solution. This is about 70% experimentation, and 30% actual use.

Is this viable? I was thinking of buying something like [this Cypress USB controller](http://www.cypress.com/?rID=99916), in conjunction with a PCI bus master board, and (I'm guessing) a microcontroller to interface the two.

I'm not experienced in this, which is why I want to learn... I am an EE, but not this advanced.

Is this doable? Would it be possible as a long term learn-and-do project?

Comment: The greatest challenge here is likely to be drivers and OS support. How do you make your OS recognize a PCI device made available over USB? Once you've figured out how to write a kernel driver that can bridge the two interfaces, you can start thinking about electrical implementations.

Comment: @NickJohnson Ahh! So I guess I need to read up on the specs, and get some sample drivers first. But is it required to bridge the interfaces? Instead can I not simply implement the PCI bus as a virtual device?

Comment: Possibly - that would depend on OS support. Once you've determined if and how it can be implemented in the OS, and how you'll encapsulate PCI transactions over USB, you'll hopefully have more details on the requirements for your hardware. I would hazard a guess that your best solution will be to use an FPGA, which will be able to speak both USB and PCI natively. As a potential project, it's very much jumping in the deep end - you probably want to start by learning FPGA and OS kernel driver basics!

Comment: Since you mentioned Cypress devices, you may want to take a look at the [Cypress PSOC](http://www.cypress.com/psoc/?source=CY-ENG-HEADER) chips. They can give you the USB controller and microcontroller in one package, and even provide Windows drivers for them (they open a virtual serial port). You may be able to add a wrapper around this driver instead of writing it completely from scratch. Given the FPGA fabric they have onboard, you may even be able to implement the PCI controller in there too.

Comment: @skrrgwasme great info, thanks, looking it up. Why don't you write it as an answer? I'm guessing that the 8051 won't be sufficient, and I'll have to go with the kit with the cortex CPU.

Comment: Maybe this might work http://www.instructables.com/id/Running-mini-PCI-e-3G-card-with-USB-mini-PCI-e-t/ but I haven't tried it. You should be able to use a PCIe x16 card using something like EXP GDC Beast

Answer (score 3):

There are two challenges:

1. Latency

   USB has two orders of magnitude higher latency than PCI. Many PCI drivers assume memory mapped access to registers on the PCI card with the CPU blocking on the bus transaction. Unmodified PCI drivers over a PCI-over-USB bridge are likely to fail because of wrong latency assumptions.

   Check this [study on PCI latency](http://cl.cam.ac.uk/~awm22/publications/miller2009motivating.pdf): PCI mean latency is in the order of 400ns, PCIe mean latency is in the order of 2000ns. [USB 3.0 latency according to the article you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831008/what-is-the-minimum-latency-of-usb-3-0) is in the order of 30us.
2. Bus vs. Packet Network

   While PCI is a bus, PCIe and USB are packet based networks. The PCIe root bridge hides the complexity of a packet network and presents the CPU with something that looks like a bus. Doing the same thing over USB is certainly possible, but if you want binary compatible drivers your hardware interface towards the CPU has to look more or less like PCI and you will end up with something like a PCIe root bridge. This is probably not something that can be achieved by common USB chipsets with *HCI interfaces.

Comment: Since I intend to fake the entire PCI controller, would the *HCI interface still pose a problem? I guess I'll have to use the [isochronous mode](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Isochronous) ...

Answer (score 3):

PCI cards are enumerated and assigned addresses in the host's address spaces (both memory space and IO space). The cards can DMA to anywhere in main memory and in principle even DMA to each other bypassing main memory (though this is rarely done outside of specialist kit from the likes of National Instruments).

Drivers for PCI cards don't expect to pass requests through lower level drivers. They expect to be able to talk directly to the card through the memory and/or IO map.

You can try and fake memory accesses, for example by using the virtualisation features of the host CPU but you are likely to run into significant latency issues.

I therefore find it unlikely that such an adaptor can be made to work acceptable with the existing drivers for the cards. The only viable way to make such an adaptor would likely to be to re-engineer the drivers for each card you want to work with it, carefully deciding what tasks to keep on the host computer and what tasks to move into the adapter.

If you want to use your hardware with the standard drivers then you will need an appropriate PCI-like interface to the host, such as cardbus, expresscard or thunderbolt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason it isn't doable, but you're taking on quite the project here. There are a lot of layers you'll have to implement to make it successful. Your final solution will probably look something like this:

PCI Physical -> PCI controller -> MCU translator -> USB client controller -> USB Host Driver and USB to PCI device emulation

I think your proposed approach is probably the most simple, because you would only have to program the man-in-the-middle microcontroller to be a translator between the PCI bus master and the USB controller (and the host driver). However, I like to combine hardware components wherever possible, so here are a few alternatives for you:

- System on a Chip (combines PCI Phy & bus master, MCU, and USB controller)
  System on a chip solutions, similar to the [Cypress PSoC](http://www.cypress.com/psoc/?source=CY-ENG-HEADER),could allow you to reduce extra hardware by integrating the PCI PHY layer, PCI controller, and USB controller on your device into a single chip, while still retaining the ability to do some of your work on a CPU in C instead of all in an HDL. As you have pointed out in a comment, the bandwidth of the PCI bus (133MB/s at its slowest) is far greater than FSUSB provided by Cypress for PSoC chips(~1.5MB/s), which will create bandwidth issues. That particular chip won't work for you, but I chose it as an example of a SoC since it's the only one I have worked with. You will need to find one with USB 3.0 support to meed your bandwidth requirements.
- All FPGA (combines PCI Phy & bus master, MCU, and USB controller)
  You could possibly fit all of the PCI and USB work onto a single FPGA if you're feeling confident in your HDL skills. Try looking for open-source HDL implementations of the PCI and USB protocols to save yourself some work.
- Microcontroller w/ USB 3.0 (combines MCU and USB controller)
  A third option would be to use a chip like [TI's Sitara MCUs](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/arm/sitara_arm_cortex_a_processor/products.page) that contain a USB 3.0 controller and PHY, which could be connected to your PCI bus master instead of having a separate MCU. Googling for "USB 3.0 microcontroller" shows a few other options.

Unfortunately, all of these alternatives still require a driver on the host side that can make a USB device appear as a PCI device so that something can actually use it. I don't know of any libraries that can help with this, so you may be on your own for that component.

Comment: The only problem with the PSOCs are that they implement only USB 2.0. 266MB/s for 32-bit PCI cards at 66MHz easily outstrips that.

Comment: @MilindR You're absolutely correct, and it was silly for me to not think of that. I've rewritten my answer so it looks less like a recommendation of that particular chip and describes more general approaches instead.

Answer (score 0):

The existing product is made by ARS Technologies (arstech.com). Their web site suggests that they are US based, but I don't think they are.

I don't recall if the host permitted use of existing PCI drivers or if it required a USB driver interface.

Comment: Does your point solve the OP question?

Answer (score 0):

Note: responding to an old thread. This might not what you want to hear, but these cards can be bought on Taobao in China, and therefore also very likely on Aliexpress. These cards will show up as an PCI Bus and PCI to PCI bridge. I own several for us with older hardware cards (like the Catweasel MK4)